# Making Posts on Blogspot Automatically

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, blogger, blogspot

Hello I am trying to develop a function that will make posts to my blog within the code without any sort of authorization or action from the website viewer.

I need to send two parameters, the post title and the post content.

We can assign those $title and $content

I have been working and researching this for about 2 weeks now. There is almost zero documentation on how to do this, and the documentation that does exist is out dated and very difficult to use.

Any help would be desperately appreciated.

I have been able to configure my API key correctly using the Blogger V3 API public key. I have been getting a valid return of json data, although I just need to know how to make posts.

Thank you!

```
<?php

function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}


$blogID = '2139447653782748476'; 
$apikey = '***';

$requestURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/{$blogID}?key={$apikey}";

//$requestURL = "http://icanhazip.com";

//$json = file_get_contents("http://icanhazip.com");

$json = file_get_contents_curl($requestURL);

$json = json_decode($json);

//echo $requestURL;

//var_dump($json);

var_dump($json);

//echo $json;

?>
```

Second code I tried:

```
<?php
/*
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}


if ($_GET['key'] != 'buswell') {
die();
}
/*
$blogID = '2139447653782748476'; 
$apikey = 'AIzaSyDbouGxlQ9P9JMuH4SJlq43xMhyVGWe14g';

$requestURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/{$blogID}?key={$apikey}";

//$requestURL = "http://icanhazip.com";

//$json = file_get_contents("http://icanhazip.com");

$json = file_get_contents_curl($requestURL);

$json = json_decode($json);

//echo $requestURL;

//var_dump($json);

var_dump($json);

//echo $json;

*/

session_start();
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Client.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Service/Client.php';

$scriptUri = "http://connectionincognito.com/dev.php";

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessType('online'); // default: offline
$client->setApplicationName('giaws'); //name of the application
$client->setClientId('924143111807-63s8j0f8rnn7ps3pdtnah827rvj29mnr.apps.googleusercontent.com'); //insert your client id
$client->setClientSecret('77c9742276a14988db77f8b5454f9ba378762246'); //insert your client secret
$client->setRedirectUri($scriptUri); //redirects to same url
$client->setDeveloperKey('77c9742276a14988db77f8b5454f9ba378762246'); // API key (at bottom of page)
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/blogger')); //since we are going to use blogger services

$blogger = new Google_BloggerService($client);

if (isset($_GET['logout'])) { // logout: destroy token
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
 die('Logged out.');
}

if (isset($_GET['code'])) { // we received the positive auth callback, get the token and store it in session
    $client->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) { // extract token from session and configure client
    $token = $_SESSION['token'];
    $client->setAccessToken($token);
}

if (!$client->getAccessToken()) { // auth call to google
    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
    header("Location: ".$authUrl);
    die;
}
//you can get the data about the blog by getByUrl
$data = $blogger->blogs->getByUrl(array('url'=>'http://proxies-unlimited.blogspot.com/'));

//creates a post object
$mypost = new Google_Post();
$mypost->setTitle('this is a test 1 title');
$mypost->setContent('this is a test 1 content');

$data = $blogger->posts->insert('2139447653782748476', $mypost); //post id needs here - put your blogger blog id
 var_dump($data);
?>
```

Comment: you might want to start by using the Php client library it doesn't look like you are using it currently.  https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: Hello thank you for the help, I will respond instantly as I am very appreciative sir.

Comment: Please check the code I posted below which is using the library.

Comment: please add the code below to your question because that's probably going to be removed since its not an answer.

Comment: are you talking about a blogger blog? as in something.blogspot.com
PHP does not work in blogger, blogger blogs are written in xml.

Comment: Yes making a post to a blogger blog.